# Completion of infinite projective space

Tags: projective-geometry, completion

I would like to ask for a reference regarding the completion of infinite-dimensional Projective Space (both Real and Complex). Since in the infinite-dimensional projective space you can take sequences with finitely many non-zero entries (for any large finite number), the completion would contain sequences with countably many non-zero entries. I would like to learn more about this space from any viewpoint (topological etc.). Thank you very much!